# How to configure the sgx environment on Aliyun g7t server

Tags: python, sgx

I want to run python code, so I think I need to use libos like occlum or graphene, and I want to know how to configure such an environment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not very clear, so I'm assuming you want to setup SGX+Gramine (graphene's successor) on a server.

I went through this process many times, being an SGX dev. To make things way easier, I set up [an ansible playbook](https://gitlab.com/X99/sgxsetup). If you're not familiar with ansible you can still make great use of its guts and make it your own.